# Excel: Create a Collapsible Master-Detail View From Another Sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I'm designing an excel template for importing data (into another DBMS).

The problem is, the data will be separated (normalized) into several tables in my DBMS (master-detail model).

Let's say I have two sheet **Order** and **Order Detail**.

The **Order** contains: `ORDERID, CUSTOMERID, EMPLOYEEID, ORDERDATE, REQUIRED_DATE,` and `SHIPPED_DATE`.

While **Order Detail** contains: `ORDERID, PRODUCTID,` and `QUANTITY`

I'm planning to create a template like this: 
[image]

When the Order is entered, there will be a collapsible pane to enter the Order Detail (from corresponded Order).

Is it possible to create something like this? How to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure about achieving this exact design, but you could have something functionally similar by programming a VBA user form that shows when you double click an OrderID.

Comment: How to show the details? I've try using grouping feature, but it's not appropriate. Can i create something like sub-sheet?

Comment: The best I can think of is to show the related order details in a list box on a user form (pop-up window). For updating the order detail, there would be some input fields and an Enter button on the user form. I don't know of a way to show a sub-sheet or to have it collapsible like what you've described.